# Pausing the timer

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I've the following code in my Java component. The method myLongRunningTask() gets called on every 5 second timer interval.
I need to be able to pause the timer until myLongRunningTask() method execution is completed. Wondering if this is possible?
Any thoughts would be appreciated!
(I tried using timer.cancel,but i believe it will discard any currently scheduled tasks.)

Thanks.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myLongRunningTask();    
    }
  };
    
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 2 * 1000, 5 * 1000);
```

Comment: You have two variables with the same name. What's your actual code?

Comment: Cancel the task before calling `myLongRunningTask` and reschedule it after it's complete

Comment: So you want to wait five seconds between executions? After one execution ends, wait five seconds until the next execution begins?

Comment: Mitu, don't edit your source code to adapt it to the comments.  You have been requested to post your actual code.  Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  if you want your question to be suitable for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes are legacy, having been supplanted by the Executors framework way back in Java 5. So noted in their Javadoc.

One of the [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) sub-interfaces is [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You can use this to schedule a repeating task. You have two choices in how to make that repeating schedule:

- Schedule a task to start at the start of a repeating span of time: [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))
- Schedule a task to start only after a waiting period that begins when the previous execution ends: [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

You seem to want: After one execution ends, wait five seconds until the next execution begins. If that interpretation of your Question is correct, you want the second approach bulleted above.

```java
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay( myRunnableTask, … , 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

To learn more about executor services, and most especially about how important it is to (a) not let an Exception bubble up and (b) properly shut them down before your app ends, search Stack Overflow. The topic has been addressed many times.

---

**Caveat:** If your app deploys to a [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/) compliant server that supports [*Jakarta Concurrency*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/concurrency/), use a [managed scheduled executor service](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/concurrency/3.0/jakarta-concurrency-spec-3.0#managedscheduledexecutorservice) there rather than the code shown above.